# How to apply an inner join only to a subset of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have two tables, `Students` and `Scores`:

Students

| ID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ryan | M |
| 2 | Joanna | F |
| 3 | Shelly | F |
| 4 | James | M |
| 5 | Ron | M |
| 6 | Amy | F |

Scores

| ID | StudentID | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 85 |
| 2 | 3 | 61 |
| 3 | 5 | 92 |
| 4 | 3 | 55 |
| 5 | 4 | 63 |

I want to get the names of all students, but I only want passing students for the boys. The result that I want is:

```
Ryan
Joanna
Shelly
Ron
Amy
```

The best I got is:

```
select name
from students
left join scores on (students.id=scores.student_id
      and students.gender='M'
      and scores.score > 70)
where (students.gender='M' and score is not null)
      or students.gender != 'M'
```

but here I'm checking the `gender` three times. Is there a way to do this more optimally? Is it possible to apply the gender filter once, and the score filter once?

In my mind, this operation should be equivalent to applying an inner join only to the subset of a table. But that is not the case in application. Doing so would give you back the joined subset, NOT a join applied to a subset of the entire table, as I want here.

Comment: For completeness, add an example of a female with only failing scores and how you'd like that record treated in the results.

Comment: I added two edge cases for clarification: for a failing female student, they should also show up in the results because I do not want the join applied to female students at all. For a female student that does NOT have a score at all, I also want them to show up in the final results. Essentially, I would like to keep the original Students table perfectly intact, except for a subset of the students to whom I want to apply a certain join condition.

Comment: What about a male that has no score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only require names from the `students` table you can use *exists*

```
select name
from students s
where s.gender = 'f' or (
    s.gender = 'm' and exists (
    select * from scores sc
    where sc.StudentId = s.Id and s.Score > 70
  )
);
```

Comment: Assuming `gender` is either `f` or `m` then the additional `s.gender = 'm'` is not necessary.

Comment: Yes agree it would be redundant, provided it does represent only the true biological genders. If the OP has a constraint on the column enforcing that it could be safely omitted.

Answer (score 1):

For the title question, the thing to understand is JOINs **always** apply to the *entire set*, and you use the `ON` clause to select which rows match.

So you can apply an `INNER JOIN` to a partial table by joining to a nested subquery (formally: derived table). ie:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT ...
        FROM TableB
        WHERE ...
   ) b ON ...
```

Alternatively, you get the same effect by doing all the desired filtering in the `ON` clause, which can have complicated boolean expressions:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON ...
```

---

Either way, it's important to understand that `INNER JOIN` will only include results when **both** sets have a match.

If you want to ensure you have rows from the first set that might not be in the second, **you don't really want an inner join at all**, and instead should look at an outer join (ie: `LEFT JOIN`).

---

The rest of the question is not 100% clear to me, but based on what I understood I see two ways to do this:

```
select distinct name
from students st
inner join scores sc on st.id=sc.student_id
      and (st.gender='F' OR sc.score > 70)
```

or

```
select distinct name
from students st
left join scores sc on st.id=sc.student_id
where st.gender='F' OR sc.score > 70
```